Nest.js call a controller from another service dynamically
In my Nest.js setup have a mod.service.ts in which i want to call project.controller.ts's api endpoints, i was able to call it by doing something like this
// mod.service.ts

class MockRequest implements Partial<Request> {
  headers: Headers;

  constructor(headers: Record<string, string> ) {
    for (const[key, value] of Object.entries(headers)) {
      // this.headers.set(key, value); // this fails
    }
  }
}

const requestConfig = new MockRequest({
  ...mod.headers,
  'activity': 4235534,
  'access_token': xxxxxxxxxx,
});

const response = await projectsController['abandonedProjects'].apply(projectsController, requestConfig);

I am able to get the response but the headers.set() call fails with Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') resulting in failed call overall (because it's unauthorized, so gets blocked by JWT guard).
Any idea how i can inject headers and params to it?
I have 100s of controller functions and i would like to avoid refactoring all of that logic to be in proper service methods. (as calling a service method dynamically is not as difficult it seems)
Currently i'm achieving this by making an http request to my own server which is not a good way and i want to avoid making a http network request, so i'm thinking of any better ideas.

Use NestJS's powerful dependency injection system!
refactor the logic into a service that can be used by both the controller and the other services. This way you avoid the need to make HTTP requests to your own server which is unnecessary.
Below i am writing how you can achieve this with code:
project.service.ts
@Injectable() //decorator used to mark a class as a provider managed by DIS
export class ProjectService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}  // Injecting HttpService

  async getAbandondProjects(headers: Record<string, string>) {
    const response = await this.httpService.get('foobarEndpoint', { headers }).toPromise();
    return response.data;
  }
}

project.controller.ts
@Controller('projects')
export class ProjectController {
  constructor(private readonly projectService: ProjectService) {}  // Injecting ProjectService

  @Get('abandoned')
  async abandondProjects(@Headers() headers: Record<string, string>) {
    return this.projectService.getAbandonedProjects(headers);
  }
}

the ProjectService can also be injected into the ModService through its constructor, this is DI between services
mod.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class ModService {
  constructor(private readonly projectService: ProjectService) {}  // Injecting ProjectService

  async someMethod() {
    const headers = {
      ...this.headers,
      'activity': '4235534',
      'access_token': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    };
    const abandonedProjects = await this.projectService.getAbandonedProjects(headers);
    return abandonedProjects;
  }
}

